# Reading random lines from a file and writing them to a another file

Tags: java

The `BufferedWriter` does not write to file "segfil.txt":

```
public static String fileSeg(String name, int co) throws IOException {
    String randomString = "";
    File fil5 = new File("segfil.txt");
    Random r;
    System.out.println("Dude what??");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    BufferedWriter bfwt = newBufferedWriter(newFileWriter(fil5.getName()));
    List<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line = reader.readLine();
    System.out.println(line);
    System.out.println("++++++++");
    bfwt.write(line);
    while (line != null) {
        lines.add(line);
        line = reader.readLine();
    }
    // Choose a random one from the list
    while (co > 0) {
        r = new Random();
        randomString = lines.get(r.nextInt(lines.size()));
        System.out.println(randomString);
        bfwt.write(randomString);
        System.out.println(co);
        co--;
    }
    return fil5.getName();
}
```

I have generated the random lines but cannot write to another file. The file remains blank as it is not written.

Comment: Please post the code in your question rather than providing a link to an image.

Answer (score 1):

You should use try-with-resources to automatically close the files (and hence flush, in the case of the Writer):

```
try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
     BufferedWriter bfwt = newBufferedWriter(newFileWriter(fil5.getName()))) {
  // Code using reader and bfwt.
}
```

Comment: You must assign `FileReader` resource to a variable for complete safe resource management.

Comment: @LoganMzz why? `BufferedReader`'s `close` method will call `close` on the underlying reader.

Comment: And if BufferedReader instanciation throw an exception ?

Comment: @LoganMzz Good point - consider stating the edge case that you're thinking of in your comment rather than just saying "you should do X" though, since I've obviously missed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to flush after writing?

```
bfwt.write(randomString);
bfwt.flush();
```

Or do you have any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You don't close your resources/streams. You need to improve resource management from your code. Use [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
try (
  FileReader     fileReader     = new FileReader("...");
  BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
) {
   String line;
   while ( (line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) lines.add(line);
}
```

You can also rely on `Path` and `Stream` APIs:

```
List<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("")).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Same logic apply to write:

```
Random random = ThreadLocalRandom.current();    
try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("...")) {
  for (int i = 0; i < co; i++) {
    int lineNumber = random.nextInt(lines.size());
    String line = lines.get(lineNumber);
    fileWriter.write(line);
    fileWriter.write('\n');
  }
}
```

with `Path` and `Stream` APIs:

```
Files.write(
  Paths.get("..."),
  ThreadLocalRandom.current()
    .ints(co, 0, lines.size())
    .mapToObj(lineNumber -> lines.get(lineNumber))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())
);
```